# How do you dynamically position one element on top of another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, positioning

I'm dynamically appending some html with jQuery and I want to insert it directly on top of another element. How do I do this?

this is the code in my application.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.oembed').embedly({maxWidth:300,'method':'replace'}).bind('embedly-oembed', function(e, oembed){
      $("#video_div").append($("<img>", { src: oembed.thumbnail_url, width:200 }));
   });
});
```

The image is being inserted dynamically, and I want it to be directly on top of this:

```
<div id="video_div"><%= link_to 'video', @video.video_url, :class => 'oembed' %></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with *on top*? Before it (in the page flow) or literally on top of it?

Comment: @Justin How is that other element positioned?

Comment: the other element is just the first element on the page, it has no CSS yet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is more like a CSS question. You want to make sure the parent element (#video_div) is positioned relatively (position: relative) and the inserted element (the img) is positioned absolutely (position: absolute)

Hook it to the top left, make sure they're the same size and you're golden.

```
#video_div {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#video_div img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you mean directly on top of it (obscuring it) in the z-order, a combination of JQuery's [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) method and absolute positioning should do the trick.

```
$('<div>New Element</div>').css({
    "position" : "absolute",
    "left"     : $foo.position().left,
    "top"      : $foo.position().top
}).appendTo($container);
```

Note: `$container` must contain both the dynamically generated element and the target element.

Comment: can you please show an example with the js code that I posted?

Comment: I have no idea how `.embedly()` works, but I'll post an example with standard JQuery code.